# Trying to restore a 3Gb MySQL table using mysqldump on a production server, will it slow down the server?

Tags: mysql, production-environment, database-restore

I have a 3Gb large table with 2M+ rows that is a mysql dump (.sql) file.

Quick info:

`It takes 3.69 seconds to run a count query on a table on production with 950k rows, while on my local macbook it takes 1.45 seconds to run the same count query on a similar table with 2M+ rows.`

I need to import it into a DB on a live production server while the server is doing the following:

`1. Running crons throughout the night.
 2. Numerous select and create queries are happening on other tables within the same db.
 3. DB backup will be happening at some point in the night.`

Will my carrying out this command:

`source tablename_dump.sql`

cause the the system to experience:

`1. Memory shortage (assuming I do not have infinte memory and that these crons do take up a lot of memory)
 2. Locking up of crons / backups.
 3. Any other problems I may not have considered?`

If there are issues that I should be aware of, how can I import this table into the production MySQL database.

I'm hoping that since a dump file is a series of single insert statements, MySQL will not peak, and will carry out the process in a moderate fashion till all the records have been fed in without causing any of the above issues.